# Eliminar Objeto de un Array al recorrerlo

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy trabajando con NodeJS al recuperar la información de la API REST, necesito parsearla, tengo el siguiente Objeto y necesito eliminar del array

> sensor_type

el objeto completo que no tenga el name igual que el attrName.

```
{
   "DatagreenhouseRecuperado":[
      {
         "_id":999,
         "medidas":[
            {
               "_id":"5cccb38f796936d12ef7586d",
               "marca":"Metos",
               "modelo":"Estacion",
               "fabricante":"Metos",
               "id_station":[
                  999
               ],
               "sensor_type":[
                  {
                     "name":44,
                     "type":"clima",
                     "place":"interior",
                     "img":"assets/img/hum.png",
                     "name_comun":"Temperatura",
                     "medida":"%",
                     "interfaz":""
                  },
                  {
                     "name":33,
                     "type":"clima",
                     "place":"interior",
                     "img":"assets/img/hum.png",
                     "name_comun":"Hum. Relativa",
                     "medida":"%",
                     "interfaz":""
                  }
               ],
               "attrName":33,
               "attrValue":8888,
               "recvTimeTs":1588524826,
               "recvTime":"2020-05-03T18:53:46"
            }
         ],
         "count":1
      },
      {
         "_id":191,
         "medidas":[
            {
               "_id":"5cc85899a0160f16c50f4199",
               "marca":"Hortisis",
               "modelo":"Estacion",
               "fabricante":"Hortisis",
               "id_station":[
                  191,
                  457
               ],
               "sensor_type":[
                  {
                     "name":2,
                     "type":"clima",
                     "place":"interior",
                     "img":"assets/img/hum.png",
                     "name_comun":"Hum. Relativa",
                     "medida":"%",
                     "interfaz":""
                  },
                  {
                     "name":3,
                     "type":"clima",
                     "place":"interior",
                     "img":"assets/img/hum.png",
                     "name_comun":"Hum. Relativa",
                     "medida":"%",
                     "interfaz":""
                  }
               ],
               "attrName":3,
               "attrValue":2222,
               "recvTimeTs":1554134499,
               "recvTime":"2019-09-01T16:01:11.000Z"
            }
         ],
         "count":1
      },
      {
         "_id":457,
         "medidas":[
            {
               "_id":"5cc85899a0160f16c50f4199",
               "marca":"Hortisis",
               "modelo":"Estacion",
               "fabricante":"Hortisis",
               "id_station":[
                  191,
                  457
               ],
               "sensor_type":[
                  {
                     "name":2,
                     "type":"clima",
                     "place":"interior",
                     "img":"assets/img/hum.png",
                     "name_comun":"Hum. Relativa",
                     "medida":"%",
                     "interfaz":""
                  },
                  {
                     "name":3,
                     "type":"clima",
                     "place":"interior",
                     "img":"assets/img/hum.png",
                     "name_comun":"Hum. Relativa",
                     "medida":"%",
                     "interfaz":""
                  }
               ],
               "attrName":2,
               "attrValue":555,
               "recvTimeTs":1554134471,
               "recvTime":"2019-04-01T16:01:11.000Z"
            }
         ],
         "count":1
      }
   ]
}
```

Por ejemplo en el primer caso se tendría que eliminar el objeto:

```
{
                         "name":44,
                         "type":"clima",
                         "place":"interior",
                         "img":"assets/img/hum.png",
                         "name_comun":"Temperatura",
                         "medida":"%",
                         "interfaz":""
                      }
```

ya que el attrName es 33.

No tengo muy claro como hacerlo, he pensado en recorrer todo el objeto y cuando encuentre name diferente de attrName eliminar ese objeto, pero no se como se puede borrar ese objeto y no el elemento name.

Gracias un saludo.

Comment: Suponiendo que el objeto json está en la variable vec podes hacer: delete vec.DatagreenhouseRecuperado[0].medidas[0].sensor_type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
const myArray = {
   "DatagreenhouseRecuperado":[
      {
         "_id":999,
         "medidas":[
            {
               "_id":"5cccb38f796936d12ef7586d",
               "marca":"Metos",
               "modelo":"Estacion",
               "fabricante":"Metos",
               "id_station":[
                  999
               ],
               "sensor_type":[
                  {
                     "name":44,
                     "type":"clima",
                     "place":"interior",
                     "img":"assets/img/hum.png",
                     "name_comun":"Temperatura",
                     "medida":"%",
                     "interfaz":""
                  },
                  {
                     "name":33,
                     "type":"clima",
                     "place":"interior",
                     "img":"assets/img/hum.png",
                     "name_comun":"Hum. Relativa",
                     "medida":"%",
                     "interfaz":""
                  }
               ],
               "attrName":33,
               "attrValue":8888,
               "recvTimeTs":1588524826,
               "recvTime":"2020-05-03T18:53:46"
            }
         ],
         "count":1
      },
      {
         "_id":191,
         "medidas":[
            {
               "_id":"5cc85899a0160f16c50f4199",
               "marca":"Hortisis",
               "modelo":"Estacion",
               "fabricante":"Hortisis",
               "id_station":[
                  191,
                  457
               ],
               "sensor_type":[
                  {
                     "name":2,
                     "type":"clima",
                     "place":"interior",
                     "img":"assets/img/hum.png",
                     "name_comun":"Hum. Relativa",
                     "medida":"%",
                     "interfaz":""
                  },
                  {
                     "name":3,
                     "type":"clima",
                     "place":"interior",
                     "img":"assets/img/hum.png",
                     "name_comun":"Hum. Relativa",
                     "medida":"%",
                     "interfaz":""
                  }
               ],
               "attrName":3,
               "attrValue":2222,
               "recvTimeTs":1554134499,
               "recvTime":"2019-09-01T16:01:11.000Z"
            }
         ],
         "count":1
      },
      {
         "_id":457,
         "medidas":[
            {
               "_id":"5cc85899a0160f16c50f4199",
               "marca":"Hortisis",
               "modelo":"Estacion",
               "fabricante":"Hortisis",
               "id_station":[
                  191,
                  457
               ],
               "sensor_type":[
                  {
                     "name":2,
                     "type":"clima",
                     "place":"interior",
                     "img":"assets/img/hum.png",
                     "name_comun":"Hum. Relativa",
                     "medida":"%",
                     "interfaz":""
                  },
                  {
                     "name":3,
                     "type":"clima",
                     "place":"interior",
                     "img":"assets/img/hum.png",
                     "name_comun":"Hum. Relativa",
                     "medida":"%",
                     "interfaz":""
                  }
               ],
               "attrName":2,
               "attrValue":555,
               "recvTimeTs":1554134471,
               "recvTime":"2019-04-01T16:01:11.000Z"
            }
         ],
         "count":1
      }
   ]
 };

 // primero itera DatagreenhouseRecuperado
 myArray.DatagreenhouseRecuperado.forEach(item =>
   // después iteramos item.medidas
   item.medidas.forEach(medida => {
     // después filtramos los medida.sensor_types dependiendo si 
     // sensor.name === medida.attrName
     medida.sensor_type = medida.sensor_type.filter(sensor =>
       sensor.name === medida.attrName
     )
   })
 )


 console.log(myArray.DatagreenhouseRecuperado);
```

Espero que esto sea lo que necesitas, saludos !